# My bash doesn't find Conan C/C++ package manager installed with pip

Tags: bash, pip, archlinux, conan

Exploring StackOverflow I found the Conan package manager for C/C++. I immediately wanted to try it out.
So I installed pip and the `conan` package as the [official guide](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html) recommends, but then, when I tried to run the package, my bash said

```
$ conan
bash: conan: command not found
```

So now I wonder how to use pip packages, specifically Conan, on Arch Linux without using AUR

***EDIT***

**For the people who are saying in the comments that I have to write the whole path**

There is no doubt about that. It would work.
But also in the conan installation documentation the *recommended* way to install conan is [with pip](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-with-pip-recommended) and in the [getting started](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#inspecting-dependencies) of the same documentation, the conan package is invoked as a program (apparently placed somewhere already reachable from my PATH).

In the pip documentation, it never seems to me that the need to add the package path in the PATH variable is ever mentioned (which by the way includes the python version, so after the next python update I should update the PATH variable as well in order to continue to use the installed pip packages).

**For the people that are saying that this question is not releated to conan**

Since I was trying to install and run conan in the *recommended way*, I thought that could be a *conan documentation* related question. Of course installing conan from AUR worked but is not the recommended way shown in the official conan documentation. Of course using AUR is a way to do that in *my* operative system but is a less portable solution

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu python-pip

$ pip install conan

$ pip -V
pip 20.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

$ python -V
Python 3.9.2

$ python -c "import conan; print(conan)"
<module 'conan' from '/home/anto/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conan/__init__.py'>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to `conan`. Like with *every* program: Either specify the complete path to the program, or put the directory where the program resides, into your PATH variable.

Comment: @user1934428 But shouldn't the pip packages be runnable with the command line with no path? I just followed the conan guide

Comment: Depends on exactly what you typed when you ran `pip`, and if you are using a virtual environment or not. Please show the command you typed.

Comment: Probably your pip is related to python 2, but your default python is 3, or vice-versa. You can check it by running `python -m conan`,  `python2 -m conan`, `python3 -m conan`. Anyway, this is not a Conan error, but an environment problem. Please, add your detailed steps used for install, pip version, python version, virtual env (if used) ...

Comment: @asdru : If you type in the shell a command without specifying a path explicitly, and it is not an internal command of the shell, or an alias, or a shell function, the shell searches the directories listed in the `PATH` variable for one which contains an **executable** file of this name. This is the basic principle of command execution, and not related to `pip`.

Comment: python package management is a nightmare.  There are so many possible variations and reasons that `conan` isn't in your path.  Maybe you were in a different virtual environment. Maybe the moon was rising in Sagittarius when you did the install.  Can you find the executable that it installed?  Try putting that in your PATH.  You've just discovered that not all documentation is accurate.  Some is so bad it's not even useful.  Perhaps try to fix the doc and patch it upstream.  But mostly just add it to your PATH and move on.

Comment: Since you keep referencing the official `conan` docs, their docs also recommend using a virtualenv which you should be using for python in general anyway:  [We strongly recommend using virtualenvs (virtualenvwrapper works great) for everything related to Python.](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-with-pip-recommended). Also the official docs specifically include [AUR instructions](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-from-aur-arch-linux) so I don't see how the AUR version is any less official.